# WEB API - when we have to use Entity class and object?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

Which should we prefer between both code 1 and code 2. Do you think Code1 is good approach to *simply return response data to front end*? using object or dynamic save us to create an entity (SiteSummaryResponseList)

Code 1:

```
Task<object> responseXObj = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
                responseXObj.Wait();
                return responseXObj.Result;
```

Code 2

```
Task<SiteSummaryResponseList> responseXObj = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<SiteSummaryResponseList>();
                responseXObj.Wait();
                return responseXObj.Result;
```

Comment: There is no reason to use `object` when you know the type you're dealing with.

Comment: Is there some specific reason for which you want to return an object to the front end? For example, if for some reason the front end view is not aware of the type of the object and you want to determine the passed type dynamically at runtime? If no then return a typed value.

Comment: @AntonKovachev  previously, There is a third party API which used to provide the data to front end. Due to some reasons, The front end is unable to access that 3rd party API but they can able to access through our ASP.NET web API. So, I'm creating a wrapper for that 3rd party API. However, front end has to hit our ASP.NET web api, and its call that 3rd party API and fetch the data. whatever data it fetch, has to provide the front-end.
So, I'm using object to avoid the dependency. in future, we no need to add any properties as object will take care. Please suggest If I'm wrong.